# Slow index scan on postgres12

Tags: postgresql, index, time-series-database

I have a table like that should enable index only data to be used
(Postgres-12)

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_values_2021q2
(
  ts             TIMESTAMPTZ(35, 6)                    NOT NULL,
  value          FLOAT8(17, 17) DEFAULT 'NaN' :: REAL  NOT NULL,
  sensor_id      INT4(10)                              NOT NULL,
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sensor_values_2021q2_sensor_id_timestamp_index
  ON sensor_values_2021q2 (sensor_id, ts);
CREATE INDEX sensor_values_2021q2_sensor_id_timestamp_value_index
  ON sensor_values_2021q2 (sensor_id, ts, value);
```

This is one table that exists among many partition tables but I am just querying this one to help debugging why things are slow.

Ultimately I want to get the latest value for each sensor_id. To begin that I started with trying to get the last 10 minutes of data with a query like

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT DISTINCT ON (sensor_id) sensor_id, ts, value FROM sensor_values_2021q2 sv
  WHERE sv.ts::TIMESTAMPTZ >= (NOW()::TIMESTAMPTZ + INTERVAL '-10 minute');
```

This seems really slow ? On first run I get

```
Unique  (cost=0.57..2372662.06 rows=2322 width=20) (actual time=116.977..106197.413 rows=2376 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using sensor_values_2021q2_sensor_id_timestamp_index on sensor_values_2021q2 sv  (cost=0.57..2372616.47 rows=18234 width=20) (actual time=116.973..106185.193 rows=17074 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (ts >= (now() + '-00:10:00'::interval))
Planning Time: 0.128 ms
Execution Time: 106198.833 ms
```

On the second run I get

```
Unique  (cost=0.57..2372774.91 rows=2322 width=20) (actual time=3.898..8260.538 rows=2412 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using sensor_values_2021q2_sensor_id_timestamp_index on sensor_values_2021q2 sv  (cost=0.57..2372729.33 rows=18235 width=20) (actual time=3.895..8255.034 rows=17477 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (ts >= (now() + '-00:10:00'::interval))
Planning Time: 0.159 ms
Execution Time: 8261.139 ms
```

The second run is acceptable I guess.

1, Why is the first run so slow ?

2, If its using the index scan both times why is it so much faster on the second run ? Should the index not be kept up to date ?

3, Why does it use the sensor_values_2021q2_sensor_id_timestamp_index and not sensor_values_2021q2_sensor_id_timestamp_value_index ?

Thanks

The result should be

```
620555, 2021-04-08 17:24:26.830978 +00:00,843
620556, 2021-04-08 17:24:26.830978 +00:00,1876
620211, 2021-04-08 17:24:27.003893 +00:00,855.21
```

Comment: that i did understand already but is the values and date the last one the first the biggest value. as i tried to convey it doesn't make that much sense

Comment: The last row for each sensor_id should just be the one with the latest timestamp. The values could be anything.
This is sensor data that is polled every minute for a few thousand devices. I store the timestamp and value of the sensor at polling time.

Comment: there are window functions or inner join max timestamo, see if this bring some what more speed

Comment: Does it change after you run a plain `VACUUM` on the table?

Comment: your ts column definition gives me `ERROR:  invalid type modifier`.  Also, you can't a trailing comma in postgresql lists.